# Disable device node using udev (/dev/sr0)

Tags: ubuntu, udev, dev

I am trying to disable `udev` from generating `/dev/sr0` device (my cdrom) and Im trying to write `udev` rules.

I added a file `10-cd-trial.rules` in `/etc/udev/rules.d` and `/lib/udev/rules.d`, the contents are:

```
KERNEL=="sr0",SUBSYSTEM=="block",ENV{UDISKS_IGNORE}="1"
```

and ran

```
udevadm control --reload-rules
```

`/dev/sr0` hasnt been disable as yet. Am i missing something? Is it necessary I include additional rules for the device, or is my file name incorrect?

I use Ubuntu 12.10. Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Why exactly do you need to do this?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem)

Answer (score 2):

udev has no option to stop a device node in `/dev` from being created. In fact, latest udev versions don't even do that anymore; `/dev` is nowadays a *devtmpfs* where everything is created by the kernel, and udev only changes file modes, adds symlinks, etc.

Besides, the `UDISKS_IGNORE` variable is for *udisks2*, not udev. udisks does not manage `/dev` contents, but is only an interface for unprivileged programs to mount disks and manage partitions.

---

If you want to stop users from accessing the CD drive through file managers, try setting `ENV{UDISKS_SYSTEM}="1"`, `ENV{UDISKS_AUTO}="0"`, `ENV{UDISKS_SYSTEM_INTERNAL}="1"`, and `ENV{UDISKS_AUTOMOUNT_HINT}="never"` (the former two for udisks2, the latter two for udisks1).

Comment: I replaced `UDISKS_IGNORE` with `OPTIONS=="ignore_device"`, but to no avail. So since, the kernel creates the node itself, my only option is to use the options u specified.

Comment: The kernel does NOT create files. That was the case with devfs, but with devtmpfs, device files are created by udev.

Comment: @Bachsau: [Yes it does.](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/drivers/base/Kconfig?id=2b2af54a5bb6f7e80ccf78f20084b93c398c3a8b) (See "kernel-maintained" in the commit title.) Udev used to create device nodes when /dev was an ordinary blank tmpfs (before 2010 or so), but [the whole point of devtmpfs](https://lwn.net/Articles/331818/) was to avoid needing to run udev.

Comment: @user1686 But wasn't exactly that the reason to ditch devfs? Because they didn't want the kernel to manage device nodes and instead wanted to do it in userspace?

Comment: I have not used the original devfs, but according to the LWN references at least, the main reasons to ditch devfs were its unusual naming policy and its great complexity (e.g. magic module loading during path lookup). With devtmpfs the userspace can provide its own names if it wants to, e.g. udev still takes care of "/dev/disk/by-label" symlinks.